# TimeMachine restore issue

Tags: macos, terminal, time-machine, backup, command-line

Times ago I did a "restore from time machine backup" in order to restore all my files on a new SSD I bought for my macbookpro (with OSX Lion), and all went fine.
Today I installed Mountain Lion on that mac, did a new timemachine backup, then used that backup in order to configure my new retina display macbook pro… initially seemed all ok this time too… but several files were not be backedup properly and I get "corrupted settings"… for example if I use git and svn commands in the terminal it says "no command found" althought under /usr/local/ I have them installed!
What happened? The thing which scares me the more is that in previous backup the files I was working on were backedup with older version (2012)… What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your $PATH is not set correctly. All you probably need to do is set your $PATH in your shell config (.profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc… for whatever shell you are using).

For bash derived shells you can use:

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local"`

Are you sure the git binary is in `/usr/local`? One of my machines shows the git binary is in `/usr/local/git/bin` and on the other it is in `/usr/bin`.

I've got different paths for git on different machines, so maybe the new install of git put it in a different place than the old machine.